# unable to load footer whith functions.php

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, function, footer

In single-game.php

I use to call a function `$post_id = programmatically_create_post_game();` and a footer. It is working (a game is created when clicking on the button) but the footer isn't loaded. I expect the footer to be loaded when the page is displayed (clicking or not on the button).

When I do not call the function, the custom post is loaded (the button isn't working as the function is not called) but the footer is loaded.

In functions.php, the function is :

```
function programmatically_create_post_game() {
...
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_programmatically_create_post_game', 'programmatically_create_post_game' );
```

What is missing ?

Comment: Do you have `<?php get_footer();` at the end of your `single-game.php` file?

Comment: Yes, it is in the single-game.php file after the container section and the game post is correctly displayed. When I add `$post_id = programmatically_create_post_game();` in the container section, the game post is displayed but the footer is not.

Comment: Be sure not to have any closing php tags at the end of your template files. maybe in your function you have an extra closing php tag `?>`, that is closing the php tag prematurely and your `get_footer();` function can't be executed properly.

Comment: It is a good idea, gonna check now ;)

Comment: There is no php tag in the function and no extra in the single-game.php file